# JavaScript Regex (string should include only alpha, space, hyphen)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to create a regex that will match only when the string has anything but alphas, spaces, and hyphens. In other words, the string can only contain letters, spaces, and hyphens.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are looking for a test for validity:

```
// from string start to end, only contains '-' "whitespace" or 'a'-'z' 
someString.match(/^[-\sa-zA-Z]+$/)
```

Or the negation:

```
// has some invalid character not '-' "whitespace" or 'a'-'z'
someString.match(/[^-\sa-zA-Z]/)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if(someString.match(/[a-z -]+/i){
    // it's valid
}
```

Comment: "the string can only contain letters, spaces, and hyphens."

Comment: change regexp to this: /[^a-z \-]+/i

Comment: If you don't anchor your expression with ^ and $, this will simply match a substring. The rest of the string can still contain unwanted characters.