# How to restrict the data input language for applications to ENGLISH (or Latin alphabet).?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using the jquery to restrict the language by using the below code and i am unable to show warning message on when we enter other than English language.can anybody help on this issue...

```
<apex:page controller="testcontroller">
<head>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Jquery)}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {           
     $('#Demo').bind('keyup blur', function() {
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z $]/g, ''))
        var regex = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z]+$");
           if(!$(this).value().match(regex)){                                                      
        alert('Invalid Character usage. Please Use English characters only.');
                    return false;
                 }                      
            });                        
        });
    </script>
</head>
<apex:form lang="en">       
    <input Type="Text" id="Demo"/>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: You can use a much simpler regular expression than `[^a-zA-Z $]`.  Just use `/^[a-z ]*$/i`, to match a string that contains only the letters a-z and space ignoring case. Right now your regex uses `[^...$]` in a way that suggests you're trying to anchor it, but `^` and `$` inside `[]` are not anchors.

Comment: FWIW: English is not Latin and the [English Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet) is not the [Latin Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet), despite the [mis]association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your logic is not quite right.  This line

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z $]/g, ''))
```

Will replace all non-latin characters with '' (i.e. no character).  But you do this ***before*** you test for that condition and try to alert the user.

Then this line

```
var regex = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z]+$");
```

is supposed to match non-latin characters in the whole word I think, but will only match if there is a non-latin character directly before the end of word (denoted by the $ symbol).  It will never match, though, because you've already removed all the non-latin characters.

I think you would be better to try the following, I'm assuming your intention is to alert on the string and then remove the invalid characters:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {           
 $('#Demo').bind('keyup blur', function() {
       if($(this).val().match(/[^A-Za-z ]/g)){ 
           // Pop alert
           alert('Invalid Character usage. Please Use English characters only.');
           //Replace all the invalid characters with empty string
           $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z ]/g, ''))
                return false;
             }                      
        });                        
    });
```

Example on JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ozeu91yg/6/ You might want to play around with other characters, too - for instance I've kept your original form of the RegEx which allows spaces.  Do you want to also allow hyphens?  All whitespace? and so on.  Play around - anything within the [] brackets will be allowed.

---

***EDIT***

Just discovered this is a duplicate question, too - see [JavaScript Regex (string should include only alpha, space, hyphen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413118/javascript-regex-string-should-include-only-alpha-space-hyphen) for instance...

Comment: Ya Sure J Richard Snape

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in a following line:

```
if(!$(this).value().match(regex)){
```

use `.val()` instead of `.value()`

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
i am unable to show the warning message when i enter other then english language .how to i show this?can u please help on this